# How to use libraries with an Java applet?

Tags: java, html, jar, applet, manifest

The reason I have come here today is because I am experiencing difficulty running my Java applet. The applet of concern uses an external library and runs fine in the IDE; but, will not run properly in the web browser.

Specifically, it will successfully launch and features non-reliant on the library will run fine; but, when using a feature of the library, the applet does nothing.

The library I am using is contained in jgraphx.jar. Here is the source code for my HTML file, test.html:

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>Test Applet</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 Here's my first Java Applet: <BR><BR>

 <applet width="1050" height="550" archive="OAS.jar,lib/jgraphx.jar"
        code="com.OAS.OAS" />

 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

In the same directory I have test.html, OAS.jar, and a folder called lib. Inside lib is jgraphx.jar.

Inside OAS.jar are two folders, COM and META-INF. Inside META-INF is a file named MANIFEST.MF. It contains

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_07-b11 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/jgraphx.jar
```

The file structure and manifest files were automatically generated by Netbeans. I've done a lot of research and tried many different things and in my latest attempt I decided just to let the IDE handle as much as it can.

The reason I suspect that the problem is from the library is because in the beginning, the applet would not run on the webpage at all and gave me a message about being unable to access the library. After some tweaking, it now runs; but, features requiring the external library appear to not be working.

Can anybody help with my problem? Is it an issue with the HTML or the manifest files? Is it something else entirely? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your Applet into Browser than you must have to signed your JAR file first.
Here is the reference for more details:

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm uncertain signing the .jar is the issue, though. I configured Java and have my security settings at medium so I can run unsigned .jar files. Again, the applet runs and I can use some features of it. Simply the features that rely on the jgraphx.jar library don't work. It is possible that not all features run properly with unsigned jars so I will give that a try.

Comment: Does anybody know how to use the jarsigner tool?